# create a 3d matrix using a successive image on c#

Tags: c#, image, multidimensional-array, 3d, emgucv

I have a 100-successive image (.jpg) with size 200*450 ,

how I can reading this image as 3d matrix on c#  with size 200*450*100  ,

it’s like store them as a cube or multidimensional array ..

Is there any suggestion to do  this? Thanks

Comment: Please share code of what have you done so far

Comment: You can use GetPixel(x,y) to get at the colors. But the real issues are unclear: data structure, performance, purpose..